# Fade background content to new background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, scenekit

I want to be able to fade my background from my image `bg1` to `bg2`.

Right now I'm trying to animate it by...

```
scene.background.contents = @"bg1";
[CATransaction begin];
CABasicAnimation *displayBackground2 =
  [CABasicAnimation animation];
displayBackground2.keyPath = @"contents";
displayBackground2.toValue = @"bg2";
displayBackground2.duration = 5.0;
[scene.background addAnimation:displayBackground2
                        forKey:@"contents"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

However I get this error...

```
[SCNKit ERROR] contents is not an animatable path (from <SCNMaterialProperty: 0x170149530 | contents=bg1>)
```

It says that `scene.background.contents` in Apple's API, but I can't figure out how to animate it.

Comment: You can always just change the alpha of each image to your liking

Comment: How would you accomplish this?

Comment: Use timers to call methods at different times. The first would fade out the first background, and the second would be fired shortly after and make the second background fade in.

Comment: I do not know how to fade a SCNScene.background.contents. I also do not know how to have multiple backgrounds under this SCNMaterialProperty.

Comment: You can use images (`UIImageView`). Those are quite easy to fade. And using them as a background is quite flexible.

Comment: The soup man is correct, do what he says... :- )

Comment: You can't assign scene.background.contents to a UIImageView. I'm working with a SCNView containing a SCNScene. To my knowledge I can NOT use a UIImageView.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer if you wish to use the `UIImageView` solution.

Set the image of `bg1` and `bg2`:

```
//Declare them in header file

CGFloat imageHeight = self.height
CGFloat proportionalWidth = (height of background image / imageHeight) * self.width

//Set height and width to value of height and width of screen respectively

self.bg1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageHeight, proportionalWidth)];
[self.bg1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"the image"]];;
[self.view addSubview:self.bg1];
```

Change opacity:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: duration
                 animations: ^{[self.bg1 setAlpha: 0]}
];
```

Pretty straight forward from there. To call the methods at delayed times use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm really just wondering if I can animate `scene.background.contents`. It says I can, but despite my efforts I've been unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to animate a `SCNScene`'s `background`'s `contents` property.

However you can make the `SCNView`'s background a clear color, and remove any contents from `scene.background.contents` then structure your view hierarchy to look like this.

```
UIView
|
|_UIImageView *backgroundOne
|
|_UIImageView *backgroundTwo
|
|_SCNView *gameView
```

After that you can animate the `UIImageView`s as needed with

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:time animations:animation_block];
```